# Log rotation daemons (e.g. logadm) versus Custom bash scripts?

Tags: solaris, logging

We have a number of applications that generate fairly large (500Mb a day) logfiles that we need to archive/compress on a daily basis.

Currently, the log rotation/moving/compressions is done either via custom bash scripts and scheduled via Cron, or in the application's code itself.

What (if any) are the advantages of using a system daemon like logadm? (These are Solaris boxes).

Cheers,
Victor

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Solaris guy, but can probably answer this. Using standard system tools means people who know standard system tools can get things working more efficiently. If you need to configure something unusual you can ask people in a forum like this and they can help. On the other hand, even if you use a system daemon for the main task, you will probably want to add some monitoring to the task to alert you of any problems, and so you are back to writing a little bash code again.

Comment: Agreed. Prefer standard tools that people can share and speak the same language. I work in an environment full of little custom made scripts for tons of things that there are special tools already built that it makes my brain go crazy. Stop tool sprawl while you can.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at a similar question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/214745/benefits-of-log-rotation). This question can be useful even if talking about `logrotate` which should be similar to `logadm` in solaris.

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, that link is dealing with logrotation in general - we are definitely doing logrotation, it's just a question of whether using bashscripts, or a system tool like logadm. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

My preference is to have the application do it if possible.  I like to keep applications self contained with no OS level configuration, so they can be migrated between servers easily.  This especially goes for Java applications, because they can be moved unchanged between different OSes that have different tools.